# i can't taking a part from href value with preg_match_all

Tags: preg-match-all

is there any way to extract a part from href value?
For example my code is :

```
$searchfrom = '@<a class="uye" href="index.php?profil=12" contenteditable="false">@';
$search = '@<a class="uye" href="index.php?profil=(.*?)" contenteditable="false">@';
preg_match_all($search,$searchfrom,$sonuc);
```

i want to extract 12 from searchfrom variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made 3 errors but your pattern doesn't work for only one reason.

**How to write a literal string in a pattern?**

`?` is a special character in a regex and means *optional* (after a character) or turn a quantifier to lazy (after `+`, `*`, `?`, `{n,m}`) or is part of syntax for several features (non capturing or atomic groups, conditionals, recursion, definitions).
If you want to write it as literal in a pattern, you must escape it:

```
php?profil => php\?profil
```

This is the only reason your pattern doesn't work.

The same with a literal dot. `.` has a special meaning and must be escaped:

```
index.php => index\.php
```

But since `.` means *all characters*, it matches the literal dot too.

There are twelve special characters that must be escaped in a pattern to be used as literal:

```
[ ( ) { ? * + ^ $ \ | .
```

*Note that when the opening curly bracket `{` is not followed by something like this: `2,5}` or `,5}` or `2,}`, the situation isn't ambiguous (i.e. the opening curly bracket is not the begining of a `{n,m}` quantifier.) and you don't need to escape it.*

However an other character must be escaped: the pattern delimiter.

With PHP you must use a pattern delimiter to enclose a pattern, the most used is the slash `/` but you can use an other character like `~` `#` `@` ... *(note that using a regex special character or a character that is used as literal many times in the pattern is a bad idea.)*

You seems to have forgotten to put the delimiters since the `@` are part of the original string. In the pattern, the `@` is seen as a delimiter because it is the first character, but it is not seen as a literal `@`. If you want to match the `@` you must enclose your pattern with delimiters.

So, the correct pattern is :

```
$search = '/@<a class="uye" href="index\.php\?profil=(.*?)" contenteditable="false">@/';
```

If you want to avoid to search and escape each special character in a literal string, you can enclose your literal string between `\Q....\E`:

```
$search = '/\Q@<a class="uye" href="index.php?profil=\E(.*?)\Q" contenteditable="false">@\E/';
```

*(the pattern delimiter (if present), must always be escaped.)*

Or you can use the `preg_quote()` function:

```
$search = '/' . preg_quote('@<a class="uye" href="index.php?profil=', '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote('" contenteditable="false">@', '/') .'/';
```

*The second (optional) argument of `preg_quote()` is the delimiter. I have written it, but it is `/` by default.*

Comment: thank you so much for this great answer. now i understood logic of regex